# Copy a CRL that was created in Go

Tags: java, go, x509, pki, certificate-revocation

I created a CRL in Go (parsed it into PEM) and now I want to re-create the exact same CRL in Java (to obtain the same PEM). However, I'm not sure how to do this, I find that the CRL classes in Go and Java are very different.

I created the CRL in Golang the following way:

```
var revokedCerts []pkix.RevokedCertificate

clientRevocation := pkix.RevokedCertificate{
    SerialNumber:   clientCert.SerialNumber,
    RevocationTime: timeToUseInRevocation.UTC(),
}

revokedCerts = append(revokedCerts, clientRevocation)


crlSubject := pkix.Name{
    Organization:  []string{"testorg", "TestOrg"},
    StreetAddress: []string{"TestAddress"},
    PostalCode:    []string{"0"},
    Province:      []string{"TestProvince"},
    Locality:      []string{"TestLocality"},
    Country:       []string{"TestCountry"},
    CommonName:    "Test Name",
}

var sigAlgorithm pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier
sigAlgorithm.Algorithm = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 2, 840, 113549, 1, 1, 11}
sigAlgorithm.Parameters = asn1.NullRawValue

tbsCertList := pkix.TBSCertificateList{
    Version:             1,
    Signature:           sigAlgorithm,
    Issuer:              crlSubject.ToRDNSequence(),
    ThisUpdate:          timeToUseInRevocation,
    NextUpdate:          timeToUseInRevocation.Add(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(86400000)),
    RevokedCertificates: revokedCerts,
}
newCRL, err := asn1.Marshal(pkix.CertificateList{
    TBSCertList:        tbsCertList, // new CRL
    SignatureAlgorithm: sigAlgorithm,
    SignatureValue:     asn1.BitString{}, 
})
crlCreated, err := x509.ParseCRL(newCRL)

//CRL pem Block
crlPemBlock := &pem.Block{
    Type:  "X509 CRL",
    Bytes: newCRL,
}

var crlBuffer bytes.Buffer
err = pem.Encode(&crlBuffer, crlPemBlock)
```

I want to reproduce this in Java.
I am aware that I have variables (e.g. crl signature) that are empty/nil. That is for the purpose of what I want to do.
I could take the PEM and read to a CRL in Java but I'm not being able to do so to create the exact same CRL.

I want to create the CRL in Java also without a signature (all parameters equal).